# How to use Java Optional to convert a complex if condition

Tags: java, if-statement, option-type

Consider the following class

```
Class RequestBodyResource {
    private RequestVariable1 att1;
    private String att2;
    private String att3;
}
```

I have a method that should return false in 2 conditions

- If all the 3 attributes of the RequestBodyResource Object is null/empty
- If more than one attribute is not null

Basically "at least one" OR "at most one"

The code for the same is as

```
public boolean validateExactlyOneRequiredRequestParam(RequestBodyResource request) {

    //The below 3 conditions are to test that only one request is present
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt3()) && null != request.getAtt1()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt2()) && null != request.getAtt1()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt3()) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt2())) {
        return false;
    }

    //The below condition is to test that at least one request is present
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getAtt3()) && null == request.getAtt1() && StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getAtt2())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to use Java 8 Optional to make this code much easier to write and read?

Comment: What is "at the same time?"

Comment: @nullpointer - correct

Comment: Then your first condition is a subset of the 2nd condition. If all are null/empty, then it could never fulfill at least one populated attribute condition.

Comment: @Jai : I should return FALSE if all the 3 attributes are null. I should also return FALSE if more than 1 attribute is not null. How is the first condition subset of the other?

Comment: I was asking actually, which one of those do you want to check, that "at least one attribute should be there and more is not a problem" or such that "only one attribute should be there and none other"?

Comment: This is a lot confusing? Though I think it as **Exactly One**.

Comment: Naming a method `validateExactlyOneRequiredRequestParam` would make much more sense.

Comment: @nullpointer I just got it... False if not 0 or >1 non-nulls, means true if 1. Too much negation here...

Comment: The current code is not consistent with the rule as it return true if ALL are present whereas it should return false as if all are present then more than 1 is not null

Comment: @nullpointer thanks, I added your suggested name to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelWiles: If all are NOT NULL, the first if-condition will itself return FALSE.

Comment: @vivekp it's the last condition that checks for that state.

Comment: @MichaelWiles - Last condition checks for ALL NULL possibility.

Comment: @MichaelWiles - What is your question? What is not working in my above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just count?

```
int count = 0;
if(request.getAtt1() !=null) {
    count++;
}
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt2())) {
    count++;
}
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getAtt3())) {
    count++;
}

return count == 1;
```

Version with `Optional` (do not use, it is added just for fun).

```
    return Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt1()).map(ignore -> 1).orElse(0)
            + Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt2()).map(ignore -> 1).orElse(0)
            + Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt3()).map(ignore -> 1).orElse(0) 
           == 1;
```

Also it lack of check of empty strings.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer. I have upvoted it.
I'm curious if there's a much cleaner answer through Optional which avoids null checks.

Comment: There is no null check in my code (they are inside `isNotEmpty`). If you specifically insist on using `Optional` I will add another version, but it is worse.

Comment: @vivekp There is no reason to avoid null checks when you *need* to check for nulls. Using API to do that simply shifts the same thing to the API level (but the check is still present).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for an `Optional` here as such. If you just need to check if ***at least one*** of those attributes are present, you could simply check it as:

```
public boolean validateAtLeastOneRequiredRequestParam(RequestBodyResource request) {
    return request.getAtt1() != null 
            || !StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getAtt3()) 
            || !StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getAtt2());
}
```

***Edit 1***: For an ***exactly one*** check, not so good yet more readable(IMHO) than your current solution would be:

```
public boolean validateExactlyOneRequiredRequestParam(RequestBodyResource request) {
    long countPresentAttribute = Stream.of(request.getAtt2(), request.getAtt3())
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
            .count() + 
            Stream.of(request.getAtt1()).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
    return countPresentAttribute == 1;
}
```

***Edit 2***: Using `Optional` and getting rid of an external dependency on `StringUtils`, you could do it as :

```
public boolean validateExactlyOneRequiredRequestParam(RequestBodyResource request) {
    long countPresentAttribute = Stream.of(
                Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt1()),
                Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt2()).filter(String::isEmpty),
                Optional.ofNullable(request.getAtt3()).filter(String::isEmpty))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .count();
    return countPresentAttribute == 1;
}
```